# $ord_p(a)=2 \iff a\equiv -1 \mod p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> a) Let $p$ be an odd prime. Prove that:
>
> $$\text{ord}_p(a)=2 \iff a\equiv -1 \mod p$$

My attempt:

Assume that $\text{ord}_p(a)=2$, then

$a^2\equiv 1 \mod p$

$p\mid a^2-1$

$p\mid(a-1)(a+1)$

$p\mid a-1$ or $p\mid a+1$

If $p\mid a-1$ then $a\equiv 1 \mod p$

Which contradicts that $\text{ord}_p(a)=2$

Therefore, we must have $a\equiv -1 \mod p$.

Now, assume that $a\equiv -1 \mod p$

Then $a^2 \equiv 1 \mod p$. Now, I think we must show that $2$, is the least positive integer satisfying the last congruence. This is equivalent to showing, that $a\not \equiv 1 \mod p$. Since $a\equiv -1 \mod p$, then $a\not \equiv 1 \mod p$. Is that true, please?

> b) Suppose that $\text{ord}_n (a)=n-1$, prove that n is a prime number.

My attempt:

$\text{ord}_n (a)=n-1 \implies a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \mod n$

Then and by the converse of the Fermat’s little theorem, we have that $n$ is a prime number. [notice that $(a,n)=1$].

Is that true, please?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it could be possible only with $p=2$, and you suppose $p$ is odd.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you so much.

Comment: You're  welcome! Always glad to help!

Comment: B.t.w., non-prime numbers which satisfy that $a^{n-1}\equiv 1$ for all $a$ coprime to $n$ are called *Carmichael numbers. The smallest Carmichael number is $561=3\cdot 11\cdot 17$.

Comment: " Now, I think we must show that 2, is the least positive integer satisfying the last congruence."  uh.... he only positive integer smaller is $1$.... Sometimes one of the directions in an if and only if proof is self evident.  This is one of those times.

Comment: "Then and by the converse of the Fermat’s little theorem"  *What* converse of Fermat's Little Theorem?  Fermats Little Theorem isn't an if and only if statement so its converse need not be true.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you prof.

Comment: @fleablood you are right, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** For $b)$ your approoach is not working since the converse to FLT is not true.

Try instead the following:
$\text{ord}_n (a)=n-1$ implies that $a, a^2,... , a^{n-1}$ are distinct elements modulo n, in the set $\{1, 2, .., n-1\} \pmod{n}$.

Deduce that $1, 2,.., n-1$ are all invertible modulo n